# Node.js can't read else if or else part

Tags: node.js, if-statement, discord.js

I wrote a discord bot. "o" is the first letter of play. "atla" is skip. When I wrote -o MUSIC_NAME, music is adding queue and starting to play. And when I write again, just adding the queue. Everything is okay still here. When I wrote -atla. It's also working perfectly. But when I allow to changing auto music itself, it's changing music automatically. But the problem is here. The end of the last music not working else if (list.length === 0) block in endHandler function. How can I fix that? Thanks for your attention.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require("./config.json");
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const google = require('googleapis');
const youtube = new google.youtube_v3.Youtube({ version: 'v3', auth: "api_key" });

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "-";

let dispatcher;
let connection;
let url;
let list = [];
let cMusic;
let pStatus = false;

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    client.user.setActivity("Hymn For The Weekend", {
        type: "LISTENING",
    });
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {

if (message.author.bot) return;
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
if (!message.guild) return;

const commandBody = message.content.slice(prefix.length);
const args = commandBody.split(' ');
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === 'yardım') {
    message.reply(
        `
        Komutlar:
        -o MUSIC_NAME --> "o", oynat kelimesinden gelmekte.
        -durdur
        -devam
        -atla
        -sg --> çıkış yaptırır.
        `
    );
}

if (command === 'o') {
    mName = args.join(' ');
    if (args.length == 0) {
        message.reply("Geçersiz oynatma isteğinde bulundun. Adam ol.");
    } else {
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
            await youtube.search.list({ part: 'snippet', q: `${mName}` }, async function (err, data) { 
                if (err) { 
                    console.error('Error: ' + err);
                    message.reply('Hata: '+ err);
                } 
                if (data) { 
                    let mQueue = 0;
                    if(data.data.items[mQueue].id.kind === 'youtube#video') {
                        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data.data.items[mQueue].id.videoId;
                        console.log(url);
                    } else if (data.data.items[mQueue+1].id.kind === 'youtube#video') {
                        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data.data.items[mQueue+1].id.videoId;
                        console.log(url);
                    } else if (data.data.items[mQueue+2].id.kind === 'youtube#video') {
                        url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data.data.items[mQueue+2].id.videoId;
                        console.log(url);
                    } else {
                        message.reply("Aradığın şarkıyı bulamadım.")
                    }
                    let mObj = {
                        name: mName,
                        link: url
                    }
                    await list.push(mObj);
                    message.channel.send(`"${mObj.name}" sıraya eklendi.`);
                    if (list.length === 1 && pStatus === false) {
                        pStatus = true;
                        cMusic = list.shift();
                        dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(`${cMusic.link}`, { filter: 'audioonly' }));
                        dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                            message.reply(`${cMusic.name} çalıyorum.`);
                        });
                        endHandler();
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            message.reply("Önce sesli bir kanala katılmalısın!");
        }
    }
}

if (command === 'durdur') {
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        dispatcher.pause();
        pStatus = false;
    } else {
        message.reply("Önce sesli bir kanala katılmalısın.")
    }
}

if (command === 'devam') {
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        message.reply("Bu özellik şu an kullanımda değil.")
    } else {
        message.reply("Önce sesli bir kanala katılmalısın.")
    }
}

if (command === 'atla') {
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
        dispatcher.pause();
        pStatus = false;
        if (list.length >= 1) {
            cMusic = list.shift();
            dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(`${cMusic.link}`, { filter: 'audioonly' }));
            dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                message.reply(`${cMusic.name} çalıyorum.`);
            });
            endHandler();
        } else {
            message.reply("Liste sonlandı.");
        }
    } else {
        message.reply("Önce sesli bir kanala katılmalısın.")
    }
}

if (command === 'sg') {
    pStatus = false;
    message.reply("Ben gidiyom hoçça galın.");
    connection.disconnect();
}

const endHandler = () => {
    dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        pStatus = false;
        if (list.length >= 1) {
            message.reply("listede birden çok link var.")
            cMusic = list.shift();
            dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(`${cMusic.link}`, { filter: 'audioonly' }));
            dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                message.reply(`${cMusic.name} çalıyorum.`);
                pStatus = true;
            });
        } else if (list.length === 0) {
            message.reply("Liste sonlandı.")
            <---------!THIS PART IS NOT WORKING!--------->
        }
    });
}
});

client.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Discord bots but I don't think your `endHandler` will ever run the `else if` part the way it is because your code is always creating a new `dispatcher` when it plays the next song, but never sets up a `finish` handler for it.

```
const endHandler = () => {
    dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        pStatus = false;
        if (list.length >= 1) {
            message.reply("listede birden çok link var.")
            cMusic = list.shift();

            // A new dispatcher is created which means no `finish` event handlers exist at this point.
            dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(`${cMusic.link}`, { filter: 'audioonly' }));

            dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                message.reply(`${cMusic.name} çalıyorum.`);
                pStatus = true;
            });
        } else if (list.length === 0) {
            message.reply("Liste sonlandı.")
        }
    });
}
```

What you need to do is to register the event handler for the `finish` event again. The quickest (and possibly dirty) solution is to call `endHandler()` again:

```
const endHandler = () => {
    dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
        pStatus = false;
        if (list.length >= 1) {
            message.reply("listede birden çok link var.")
            cMusic = list.shift();

            // A new dispatcher is created which means no `finish` event handlers exist at this point.
            dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(`${cMusic.link}`, { filter: 'audioonly' }));

            dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                message.reply(`${cMusic.name} çalıyorum.`);
                pStatus = true;
            });
            endHandler();
        } else if (list.length === 0) {
            message.reply("Liste sonlandı.")
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried like this but it's not working again. Working endHandler but not working else or else if part.

Comment: @feyyum I've updated my answer as I now understand your code a bit better

Comment: It's working now. I appreciate it to you.